# add event to custom control raised in change properties

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

Create a custom control and inherit  `TextBox`; I add new properties to this control `SelectedRow` , In this `TextBox`show popup form and user select item and this item placed in to `SelectedRow` properties . this section is work correctly . now i want add event to this control that raise when  `SelectedRow` properties changed. for this purpose i declare `delegate` :

```
  public delegate void EventDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

and instance `event` from `delegate`:

```
  public event EventDelegate SelectedChange;
```

and add event invocator :

```
    protected virtual void OnSelectedChange(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventDelegate handler = SelectedChange;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

and in end step call `OnSelectedChange` from properties :

```
    public object SelectedRow 
    {
        get { return _selectedRow; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null || value == _selectedRow) return;
            _selectedRow = value;
            this.OnSelectedChange(EventArgs.Empty);

        }
    }
```

MY Problems:

1- In `OnSelectedChange` handler is always null and event not raise

2-My method is correct?

Comment: Does any mainform register for this here: public event EventDelegate SelectedChange like obj.SelectedChange += this.objOnSelectedChange;

?

Comment: yes , in my form i add :
repositoryItemButtonEditPopUp1.SelectedChange += repositoryItemButtonEditPopUp1_SelectedChange;

Comment: And why Do You need a second variable locally ?
EventDelegate handler = SelectedChange; Just fire like SelectedChange(this, new EventArgs());

Comment: @icbytes I do not know, I use sample code

Comment: on my side your code working fine.. can you share more detail.

Comment: @icbytes: the code in the question is raising the event per the recommended practice in .NET. Saving the event field's value to a local variable ensures against thread races (i.e. if another thread unsubscribed the event after the null check was done but before the invocation, then a NullReferenceException would occur). In a great deal of code, this is not needed, but proving that (even in simple code) is harder than just writing the code to be safe (which is trivial to accomplish).

Comment: @hamidrezamansouri: you need to post a better question, one with a good, complete, concise code example. The code you included here looks fine, so whatever the problem, it's in the code you didn't post. It seems the event handler is not being subscribed, or it is being unsubscribed later before the event is raised. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Peter Duniho. To pass global rvent to local var is state of art in .net? Really? Can You clarify Your argument a bit more in detail?